# Debugger attribute view for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

is there in python something like a decorator for IDE's or debuggers like IDLE or Visual Studio where I can configure which variable should be written in the variable view for a class?

Example code:

```
idList = []
idList.append("X342")
idList.append(Token("X9999"))
```

and the variable view in Visual Studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Q0I.png

Instead of the "Tokens.Token object at (...)" i want to specify in the Token class what the debugger should write. In this case the str "X9999".

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger almost certainly uses the `repr()` of the object. You can define your own:

```
class Token(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Token %s>" % self.id
```

If `Token` is a class from a library, you can subclass it and use the subclass, or if that's not possible, monkey-patch the original class to override its `__repr__`. The latter looks something like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<Token %s>" % self.id   # or wherever `X9999` is stored

Token.__repr__ = __repr__
```

Comment: Thank you!
I only tried it with str() but you're right I should use repr().